# JQuery Pass Parameter as Vars in 2 functions returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameters

I have the following code and I dont know why it is returning trackingIds[i] as undefined in the View and Click function... I want to fill an array and the code should go through each array index and checks if element is hovered or clicked. el_id and trackingIds[i] in the first function return the correct values. I would appreciate any help because I cant seem to figure this out.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var trackingIds = ["elementid"];

for(i=0; i<trackingIds.length; i++){
    var el_id = jQuery('#'+trackingIds[i]);
    console.log(el_id);
    console.log(trackingIds[i]);
    el_id.click(function() { Click(trackingIds[i]);});
    el_id.mouseover(function() { View(trackingIds[i]);});
}
});

function Click(a) {
 //do stuff...
 console.log("Click was called from:"+a);
}

function View(b){
 // do stuff..
 console.log("View was called from:"+b)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `let` in your `for-loop`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var trackingIds = ["elementid"];

  for (let i = 0; i < trackingIds.length; i++) {
    var el_id = jQuery('#' + trackingIds[i]);
    //console.log(el_id);
    //console.log(trackingIds[i]);
    el_id.click(function() {
      Click(trackingIds[i]);
    });
    
    el_id.mouseover(function() {
      View(trackingIds[i]);
    });
  }
});

function Click(a) {
  //do stuff...
  console.log("Click was called from: " + a);
}

function View(b) {
  // do stuff..
  console.log("View was called from: " + b)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='elementid'>Click me!</h1>
```

## Resource

- [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

  > The `let` statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard this before, will check the reference

Comment: The use of forEach off of trackingIds, rather than a basic for loop, could also create the context desired with the index being passed into the method.